# What are these valueless attributes added to my Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I've barely made any changes to the default ASP.NET Core 6 Razor Pages template, but by default it creates these valueless attributes in the rendered HTML:

```
<div b-nhqxrkkbzm class="container">
    <main b-nhqxrkkbzm role="main" class="pb-3">
```

The .cshtml source looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
```

What are these attributes, what do they do, and how are they being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new feature about CSS isolation in .Net6, you can find it in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#css-isolation).

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. It's actually a neat feature, it's just the randomly generated attribute names make my code smell bad. Now I know what it is and what it does I can make it fit in better.